# In Firebase Realtime Database, is there an advantage to attaching a .childChanged listener at main node instead of many observers to the children?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Realtime Database for a card game between players. Sometimes I am seeing logs of clients with disconnected sockets (monitoring with onDisconnect action), and players cannot continue game. My main structure is a game key register with about 14 observers attached to individual children listening for changes/register deletes/register additions.

My next steps I'm looking at to help are:

1. One observer on game register that listens for child changed, verses having individual children observed.
2. Using .keepsynced() on observers
3. Enabling disc persistence
4. Calling firebase function .goOnline() when client sees it's socket disconnect.

Any advice is appreciated :)
Many thanks!

Comment: There's a great general answer by @frankvanpuffelen but it's going to be hard to accurately answer. There are 14 observers, which won't cause disconnects. Changing the process to observing at a higher level may not make any sense. e.g. if the app only observes games the user is involved in, why add an observer for all games? That's a lot more bandwidth (as mentioned in the answer). Do you need .keepsynced? What will disk persistence help? Without understanding the use case, it's impossible to answer fully. Can you narrow the question to a SINGLE question, including the code you've attempted?

Comment: Thank you, this is a great response. I posed new refined question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74424454/in-firebase-realtime-database-if-a-client-socket-disconnects-can-i-manually-rec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you register any `child_*` listener on a parent node, the SDK synchronizes all nodes under that location/query. So if you have many child nodes under a path and only need to monitor a few of them for changes, it may be more efficient bandwidth-wise to monitor the individual child nodes with a `value` listener on each.

Comment: This is great info, I had some followups as well, here's a refined question if you are would wonderfully provide more info :), many thank yous! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74424454/in-firebase-realtime-database-if-a-client-socket-disconnects-can-i-manually-rec