# In Firebase Realtime Database, if a client socket disconnects can I manually reconnect it for them?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have a card game where I see some client sockets disconnect and the game gets hung up. Client observer(s) will miss a database event which hangs the game, but then continue seeing new updates after. So presumably the socket re-connected itself.

I am logging disconnects and app minimized states. Disconnects occur without client minimizing or closing app. When this happens, can/should I attempt to re-connect the socket manually and/or re-call any observers again to ensure when the socket re-connects any missed database events are captured. It seems during disconnect, any events during that time are missed.

```
{ "uniqueGameKey_ID_99987": {
"PlayedCards": {
  "0": "ace_club",
  "1": "king_spade",
  "2": "ten_diamond"
},
"Msgs": {
  "p1": "Hello",
  "p2": "Hi"
},
"Score": {
  "p1": 10,
  "p2": 12
},
"ReadyUp": {
  "p1": true,
  "p2": false
}
}
```

I have observers on each node 'played cards', 'Msgs', 'Score', 'ReadyUp' and many more in the gameKey.

It seems client socket disconnects and does not see opponent "ReadyUp", and if it does reconnect, it may not be re-syncing that particular listener and game hangs.

Will any of the following help?

- placing a "keepsynced()" on the readyUp listener
- when client disconnects, call .goOnline() and re-run observers?
- re-run observers if/when socket automatically re-connects?

Would love any advice here :)
Thank you!

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database SDK automatically maintains the connection, and (on Android) only closes it when the app hasn't had any listener or writes for at least 5m. On other platforms it should be even less frequently. And in all cases it should automatically try to reconnect if something relevant happens.

Comment: If you're seeing different behavior: please edit your question with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including [debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)